# Select only part of the string with regex

Tags: regex, nginx, lua

I have 2 strings:

```
$ip =        [{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}]
$port =      [{"port":"80"}]
```

I want to keep only `$ip = 127.0.0.1` for the first and`$port = 80` for the second. How should I do with Regex?

//////////UPDATE//////////

I do this and it works but it's badly written :

```
   ip = string.match(respIp.body, "%:(.*)");
   ip = string.match(ip, "(.*)%}");
   ip = string.sub(ip, 2, string.len(ip)-1);

   port = string.match(respPort.body, "%:(.*)");
   port = string.match(port, "(.*)%}");
   port = string.sub(port, 2, string.len(port)-1);
```

Comment: I dont know anything about nginx, but I woud do a replace with the regex `replace_filter '[[\]{}"]' '' g;`

Comment: @Leyffda
I updated my post. If you have ideas to better rewrite I am interested.

Comment: How about `_, _, ip2 = string.find(ip, '"ip":"([^"]+)')`?

Comment: One solution for both strings: `s:match('"([%d.]+)"')`

Comment: Is `$ip =        `  part of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `/([$]ip =).+(?<=:")([\d.]+)/g` then get group 1 and 2

[Online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rb0qv5ov/1/)

but if you want just get another character and delete them use `(?:([\[\]\{\}\":]+)|(ip")|(port")|\s{2,})`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/OgN5tC/1)

Comment: Thanks, it's better written

Answer (score 0):

ip - match any ip4 format string ,
port - match any decimal characters between double quotes

```
local bodyIp   = '$ip =        [{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}] '
local bodyPort = '$port =      [{"port":"80"}] '


local ip = bodyIp:match('(%d+%.%d+%.%d+%.%d+)') -- any ip
local port = bodyPort:match(':"(%d+)"') --  

print(ip,port)
```